# Get system brightness event in windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wmi, brightness

Can somebody will guide me how to get **brightness changes event** using **vc++** in windows system?
or I need to get brightness slider value whenever it will change.
Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by brightness changes? What brightness?

Comment: Say in laptop or tablet of having windows OS, we can change the brightness of system, right? So, I need to get that event when brightness will change.@Spook

Comment: Sure, but AFAIK this is not a value related to operating system (at least on Windows). Each notebook or tablet has its own drivers, which are responsible for passing the hardware information about brightness. I hardly doubt there's a generic way of accessing this information.

Comment: Any brightness device having attributes like `currentbrightness`, `level`, `levels`. Value of these thing use to change according to device. rest it is possible to have common interface.@Spook

Comment: @RavindraGupta - You should take a look at this post for an expansion on what Spook said. It also mentions a function possibly of use: `SetMonitorBrightness` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874615/trying-to-open-display-device-handle-to-change-brightness-on-windows-xp-using-c

Comment: @enhzflep: thanks for your answer but `SetMonitorBrightness` method is used to change the brightness of monitor, say you have LCD system for. This will not work for laptop or tablet those are running on battery. And I don't need to set the brightness, I need to get event for that.

Comment: @RavindraGupta - you're welcome. I tend to agree with Spook's sentiments - namely, this is not a windows feature, but rather one of the device driver's. To change it on my laptop, I either use a hardware key-combination (Fn & Up / Fn & Down) or I use the Power Options of the control panel. Since the Power Options available to various machines depends on their hardware, I think you'll find that the power-options control panel applet on all laptops will be one made by the manufacturer, not Microsoft. I hope and doubt you'll find the answer you want. :)

Comment: @enhzflep,@Spook:Ya agree on that point. But still say for one device/manufacturer , how to get event for brightness change?
I didn't get any idea about on this after a long hour of googling.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to reverse-engineer the control-panel applet or the device-driver itself (I'd start with the applet) You may be able to effectively do this with either OllyDbg or the free version of IDA Pro Advanced. I.e - I think you're venturing _far_ out of the territory of documentation - certainly beyond any path I've travelled (and see cause to, for that matter) Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

A late answer but since I have been looking for the same thing. Although it is true that controlling brightness is not a Windows task but sometimes a driver's task and could also be related directly to ACPI calls, we can still get some information from Windows about its changes by implementing WMI Events. In particular, you will need to implement WmiMonitorBrightnessEvent which will give you the information you need whenever Windows receives an event of brightness change. The sample code below is a direct conversion to C++/CLI of the C# code in @RRUZ answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702737/how-to-consume-wmi-events-in-c-sharp) where he made use of WmiMonitorBrightnessEvent.

**EventWatcherAsync.h**

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Management;

ref class EventWatcherAsync
{
public:
    void WmiEventHandler(Object^ sender, EventArrivedEventArgs^ e);
    EventWatcherAsync();
};
```

**EventWatcherAsync.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "EventWatcherAsync.h"

void EventWatcherAsync::WmiEventHandler(Object^ sender, EventArrivedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Console::WriteLine("Active :          " + e->NewEvent->Properties["Active"]->Value->ToString());
    Console::WriteLine("Brightness :      " + e->NewEvent->Properties["Brightness"]->Value->ToString());
    Console::WriteLine("InstanceName :    " + e->NewEvent->Properties["InstanceName"]->Value->ToString());
}

EventWatcherAsync::EventWatcherAsync()
{
    try
    {
        System::String^ ComputerName = "localhost";
        System::String^ WmiQuery;
        ManagementEventWatcher^ Watcher;
        ManagementScope^ Scope;


        if (ComputerName != "localhost")
        {
            ConnectionOptions^ Conn = gcnew ConnectionOptions();
            Conn->Username = "";
            Conn->Password = "";
            Conn->Authority = "ntlmdomain:DOMAIN";
            Scope = gcnew ManagementScope(String::Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\WMI", ComputerName), Conn);
        }
        else
            Scope = gcnew ManagementScope(String::Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\WMI", ComputerName));
        Scope->Connect();

        WmiQuery = "Select * From WmiMonitorBrightnessEvent";

        Watcher = gcnew ManagementEventWatcher(Scope, gcnew EventQuery(WmiQuery));
        Watcher->EventArrived += gcnew EventArrivedEventHandler(this, &EventWatcherAsync::WmiEventHandler);
        Watcher->Start();
        Console::Read();
        Watcher->Stop();
    }
    catch (Exception^ e)
    {
        Console::WriteLine("Exception {0} Trace {1}", e->Message, e->StackTrace);
    }
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "EventWatcherAsync.h"

using namespace System;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine("Listening {0}", "WmiMonitorBrightnessEvent");
    Console::WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
    EventWatcherAsync^ eventWatcher = gcnew EventWatcherAsync();
    Console::Read();
    return 0;
}
```