# Is it possible to hook a callback to be called when a new user is created in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, callback, wmi, user-accounts

I have a windows service that needs to be notified when a new user account in created in Windows.
Is that possible through a Windows API in C# or WMI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/2007/10/14/enumerating-users-using-wminet-and-c/ also have you thought about AD(Active Directory)

Comment: @DJKRAZE, Thank you for the suggestion. The blog tells how to enumerate user accounts using WMI. What I need is to receive a notification in order to avoid polling all the time.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393011(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: [WMI Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702737/how-to-consume-wmi-events-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to use this information in my solution.